# How to get variables using POST in PHP

Tags: php, rest

I am developing an API using PHP , What I want to do is to get variables values using Post method .

Is there anyway I can do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get variables from the URL as POST, you need to use GET. 
This is how they built it. POST variables are not accessible from the URL, its more secure, and are used for sending Usernames, Passwords.

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for more info.